# New tag angles for the new TikZ library

Tags: discussion, tagging

I tried creating the tag [angles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angles) but I was told I cannot since the tag [angle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angle) exists.  The angle tag is for `pst-eucl`.

I think we need a tag for the TikZ `angles` library as well.

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Without starting a new post, how can I create the tag `tikz-angles`?  I went to the tags tab and I couldn't find a way to do so.  We can use this tag for the new `angles` library in `TikZ`.

Comment: There is no tag [tag:angles] that exist at the moment, although there is [tag:angle]. What would be your suggestion for a TikZ angles tag? `tikz-angles`?

Comment: @Werner I know.  I think we need one.

Comment: `tikz-angles` sounds good.

Comment: What is the actual question here (just to be clear)?

Comment: @Werner original I was asking if it would okay to create the tag.  Now I just want to know how to do it without creating a random new post.

Comment: I think angles is a very small detail to have its own tag. Specifically it merely marks the angle with a label. There are many other TikZ libraries that don't have their own tag (thankfully). I'm not sure if we should actually create one.

Comment: @percusse if you do a search for angle and quotes (I use quotes in the search to limit the post that aren't about the correct angle), you will see there are many post on this library.  If there is a lot of post on the topic, wouldn't that justify a new tag?

Comment: Tags are about classifying questions not bookmarking. You can also search for page width and you would get lots of results. But they are usually under `page-size` or `geometry`

Comment: @percusse th current angle tag states for pst-eucl which doesn't make sense for someone with a question on Tikz angles.

Comment: That is a mistake that we should fix. It is used as a synonym indeed and instead we have to remove that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag creation can't be achieved as a stand-alone process. That is, [to create a tag, one must apply it to an existing question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/168244). The reasoning here may involve the requirement of the [Create Tags privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) obtained at 300 reputation.

Comment: I went ahead and created the tag on a post.